# How to lock in a chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, postfix-mta

I am attempting to run Vagrant with Chef, however am running into the current bug ;

[https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-3989?focusedCommentId=43724&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-43724](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-3989?focusedCommentId=43724&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-43724)

`[2013-11-12T15:47:30+00:00] FATAL: SyntaxError: compile error
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postfix/metadata.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
display_name: 'postfix/main',`

This commenter states they fixed it by doing the following :

`I locked my postfix recipe usage at 3.0.2 in the meantime`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Upgrade your Ruby

You are running Ruby < 1.9. The currently supported version of Ruby is 2.1 and the 1.8 series is deprecated and 1.9 series is scheduled for deprecation.

1. Change the version

What the commenter really meant was "use an older version of the cookbook". You can do this by specifying the `-v` flag to knife or downloading an older version from the community site.